# SQL query for top 3 sold out product based on Date in last 7 days

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want top 3 sold out products of last week.

Here is my sql query.

```
select   ProductId,sum(Quantity) as quantity,createdOn from

(SELECT  inv.Id,invd.ProductId, invd.Quantity  ,cast (inv.CreatedOn as date) as createdOn FROM Invoice as inv 
INNER JOIN 
InvoiceDetail invd
ON
invd.InvoiceId = inv.id
WHERE inv.CreatedOn  >= DATEADD(day,-11117, GETDATE()) ) as tbl 
group by createdOn , ProductId 
ORDER BY createdOn DESC
```

But  I didn't getting top 3 products per date. If I use TOP 3 then it will give only top 3 products while I want top 3 products per day for last week.

This is the Out put I am having. **But I want only 3 records per day.**
[image]

EXPECTED OUTPUT :
[image]

Comment: `top` is used in `sqlserver`,please keep your tag correct!

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: I provided result of that query.

Comment: There are many same `Quantity`  in  `ProductId`, what's your expect result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use `Row_number` with [windows function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to get top 3 `quantity` per day.

Make row numbers  by `createdon` per day, Based on the order of `quantity` columnfrom high to low.

```
   ;WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT productid,quantity,createdon,Row_number() over(partition by createdon ORDER BY quantity DESC,productid DESC) as RN
    FROM 
    ( 
        SELECT    invd.productid, 
                  sum(invd.quantity) as quantity, 
                  cast(inv.createdon AS date) AS createdon
        FROM      invoice  AS inv INNER JOIN invoicedetail invd
        ON         invd.invoiceid = inv.id 
        WHERE      inv.createdon >= dateadd(day,-11117, getdate()) 
        GROUP BY cast(inv.createdon AS date), invd.productid
    ) AS tbl 
)
SELECT * 
FROM CTE
WHERE RN <= 3
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/67b8e/5)

**[Results]**:

```
| productID | quantity |  createdon | rn |
|-----------|----------|------------|----|
|        94 |        7 | 2018-07-25 |  1 |
|      1119 |        2 | 2018-07-25 |  2 |
|      1115 |        2 | 2018-07-25 |  3 |
|        94 |        4 | 2018-07-26 |  1 |
|      1117 |        2 | 2018-07-26 |  2 |
|      1114 |        2 | 2018-07-26 |  3 |
```

Comment: Not getting expected result ! It just reorder the output on bases of productId.

Comment: @Aarsh I edit my answer and add some sqlfiddle hope can help you:)